# (Real) holomorphic vector fields on Compact Kähler manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, holomorphic-bundles

I am trying to prove Proposition 2.1.1 of [Gauduchon's note on Kähler extremal metrics](http://germanio.math.unifi.it/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/dercalabi.pdf) (pag. 67).
In order to show that, for compact Kähler manifolds, the complex Lie algebra of real holomorphic vector fields $\mathfrak{h}$ is finite-dimensional, he argues the following.

Firstly $\mathfrak{h}$ is identified with the space of holomorphic vector fields of $T^{1,0}$, which is equipped with an obvious $\overline{\partial}$ operator. Then he claims that holomorphic vector fields belong to $Ker(\overline{\partial})$ and $Ker(\overline{\partial}^*)$, being $\overline{\partial}^*$ the adjoint of $\overline{\partial}$, with respect to any compatible metric. Finally, since the kernel of the elliptic operator $\overline{\partial}^*$ + $\overline{\partial}$ is clearly finite dimensional, the result follows.

I am not able to prove that an holomorphic vector field $X$ belongs to $Ker(\overline{\partial}^*)$. When I identify $X$ with a (0,1)-form $\omega$, using the Kähler metric, it is not hard to prove that $\omega$ is $\overline{\partial}$-closed. However, expressing $\omega$ in local coordinates, I am not able to derive also the $\overline{\partial}^*$-closedness.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: [Crossposted on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/302360/21564).